# Make sure only one process handles a request associated to a row in a Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I have a PostgreSQL database (in google cloud SQL) and I have a process running in a container (on Kubernetes).
One row in this database represents a request entered by a user in a UI. The process in the container reads the database and does the work associated with the request.

Now I need to scale this process so I would like to get multiple copies of this process to run at the same time and each one to pick a task in the database. I have a field "being_handled" in the database indicating if a request is currently being handled by a process.

However, how do I deal with concurrent access to this row on my database? How do I make sure this field is only read/written by one process at the same time? Is there a mechanism in Postgresql that allows me to do that? Or do I have to implement some communication between my processes to share information about who is handling which request?

Thank you for reading

Comment: You may find a purpose-built job queue system like RabbitMQ to be easier to use and scale better.  That will also be able to handle conditions like a worker failing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would use a query like this:

```
SELECT id, ... FROM queue_table
WHERE NOT being_handled
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
LIMIT 1;

UPDATE queue_table
SET being_handled = TRUE
where id = /* id from above */;
```

Then no two processes will ever get the same row, and the query will never block.